# MariaDB Indexing

Tags: indexing, mariadb

Let's say I have a table of 200,000,000 users. For each user I have saved a certain attribute. Let it be their lastname.

I am unsure of which index type to use with MariaDB. The only queries made to the database will be in the form of `SELECT lastname FROM table WHERE username='MYUSERNAME'`.

Is it therefore the best to just define the column username as a primary key. Or do I need to do anything else? Also how long is it going to take until the index is built?

Sorry for this question, but this is my first database with more than 200.000 rows.

Comment: seaches for strings are slower and when you join other tables you will notice it.

Comment: Searches for strings are slower in general or slower than with an seperate index? What would you recommend me to do?

Comment: The table consists of only two columns, `lastname` and `username`?

Comment: yes, nothing else and only this kind of query mentioned before...

Comment: Then an index on `(username, lastname)` would be an option. It can answer the query alone. Though I'm not sure if it makes much difference here if only `(username)` was indexed. Might not be much.

Comment: Indexing on username only by adding a primary key actually lead to a huge performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
CREATE INDEX userindex on `table`(username);
```

This will index the usernames since this is what your query is searching on. This will speed up the results coming back as the username column will be indexed.

Try it and if it reduces performance just delete the index, nothing lost (although make sure you do have backups! :))

This article will help you out https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-indexes/
It says primary keys are best set at table creation and as I guess yours is already in existence that would mean either copying it and creating a primary key or just using an index.

I recently indexed a table with non unique strings as an ID and although it took a few minutes to index the speed performance was a great improvement, this table was 57m rows.

-EDIT- Just re-read and thought it was 200,000 as mentioned at the end but see it is 200,000,000 in the title, that's a hella lotta rows.

Comment: I have tried this out. The performance increases were really significant. From queries taking >5 mins down to what feels like instant. However, the index doubled the size of the database, which is probably due to the fact that I indexed one out of only two columns.

Answer (score 0):

`username` sounds like something that is "unique" and not null.  So, make it `NOT NULL` and have `PRIMARY KEY(username)`, without an `AUTO_INCREMENT` surrogate PK.

If it not unique, or cannot be `NOT NULL`, then `INDEX(username)` is very likely to be useful.

To design indexes, you *must* first know what queries you will be performing.  (If you had called it simply "col1", I would not have been able to guess at the above advice.)

There are 3 index types:

- BTree (actually B+Tree; see Wikipedia).  This is the default and the most commonly used index type.  It is efficient at finding a row given a specific value (`WHERE user_name = 'joe'`).  It is also useful for a range of values (`WHERE user_name LIKE 'Smith%'`).
- `FULLTEXT` is useful for a `TEXT` column where you want to search for "words" inside it.
- `SPATIAL` is useful for 2-dimensional data, such as geographical points on a map or other type of grid.

Comment: I have now gone with the primary key. The performace of my queries improved by a lot, while at the same time the primary key didn't increases the DB size a lot compared to the "proper" index.

Comment: @Champn - A _secondary_ index is a separate BTree.  The PK is part of the data and provides the ordering of the data.  So, yes, a judicious choice of PK can both save space and speed up certain queries.  And, meanwhile, an `AUTO_INCREMENT` is optimal for certain other tables.